# SQL Server 2005/2008 - Import a fixed width text file via the command line?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In **MySQL** I am able to create a table with fixed column widths and then can use the **load data infile** command to import a fixed width file.

For example:

```
Fixed width text file = JOHN   1234
```

Imports into table:

```
Username - CHAR(8)
Password - ChAR(4)
```

The beauty of this approach is that the file is 'chopped' up based on the column sizes defined in the **MySQL** table.

Now there is a new project requiring **SQL Server 2005**.

Does **SQL Server** have a function similar to **load data infile**?  Or is this a better approach then the one I'm taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have similar functionality with SQL Server.  I would encourage you to learn about format files.  This page, from Microsoft, does a fairly good job of explaining it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

I would also encourage you to read this blog:

[6 ways to import data into SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12)

Comment: We use BULK INSERT to load millions of rows for our import process.  These links are a good starting point.